# Mongoosastic indexes the wrong fields

Tags: elasticsearch, mongoose, mongoosastic

I have set up mongoosastic to index my documents to elastic search. The trouble is, despite the schema set, all fields are indexed.

My Schema:

```
id: { type: String, index: true },
title: String,
title_lower: { type: String, es_indexed: true, es_boost: 2.0 },
slug: String,
city: { type: String, es_indexed: true },
country: { type: String, es_indexed: true },
genre: [{ type: String, es_indexed: true }],
description: { type: String, es_indexed: true },
gallery: [{ title: String, images: { thumbnail: String, medium: String, full: String }}],
date: { start: String, end: String },
price: { min: Number, max: Number },
temperature: Number,
weather: String,
comments: [CommentSchema],
lineup: { type: [LineupSchema], es_indexed: true }
```

Here I want only title_lower, city, genre, description and lineup indexed. But checking elastic like: http://localhost:9200/events/_search I can see that all fields are added under _source.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this? I'm now having the same problem.

Comment: Never did sorry, I ended up ditching mongoosastic to better understand elasticsearch. I would highly recommend.

Comment: Having the same problem here. I suspect something is up with the `sychronize` function. What are you using to connect mongoose with elasticsearch?